# Gradle path error when running "meteor add-platform android"

Tags: gradle, meteor

I am using windows 10 and attempting to use meteor to create a test app.
 When I run the `meteor add-platform android` command, I get the output shown below.
I have set the `Android_home` variable and I can see a gradle folder in my Android Studio directory at `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\gradle`.
What is the path that I need to update and how do I do it? Do I need to create a Gradle_Home variable ?
Any suggestions would be appreciated !

Current code output :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the latest Gradle distribution
2. Create a new directory `C:\Gradle` with File Explorer.

Open a second File Explorer window and go to the directory where the Gradle distribution was downloaded. Double-click the ZIP archive to expose the content. Drag the content folder `gradle-6.4.1` to your newly created `C:\Gradle` folder.

Alternatively you can unpack the Gradle distribution ZIP into `C:\Gradle` using an archiver tool of your choice.

3. Configure your system environment

In File Explorer right-click on the This PC (or Computer) icon, then click Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environmental Variables.

Under System Variables select Path, then click Edit. Add an entry for `C:\Gradle\gradle-6.4.1\bin` Click OK to save.

4. Verify your installation
   Open a console (or a Windows command prompt) and run `gradle -v` to run gradle and display the version, e.g.:

You must close and open again your terminal if changes doesn't get reflected.